# Equivalence statement for a metric space; Munkres chapter 35 question 3

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In Munkres's Topology is the following question:

Let $X$ be a metric space, the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is bounded under every metric that gives the topology of $X$.
2. Every continuous function $\phi: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.
3. $X$ is limit point compact.

I need help proving 2. using 1.

The clue he gives is that if $\phi: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $x \mapsto (x,\phi(x))$ is an imbedding.

But the image $\phi(X)$ may not necessarily bounded, can you give me a hint for this?

For 2 implies 3:
Let $A \subset X$ be infinite without a limit point.

$\forall a \in A$ $\exists a \in U$ open in $X$ s.t $U \cap A = \{a\}$. Hence $A$ has the discrete topology as a subspace. Then any surjection $\phi$ from $A$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ is continuous. Define $j \circ \phi: A \to \mathbb{R}$ with $j$ the inclusion map, it is continuous and hence bounded by 2 in  contradiction to it being onto $\mathbb{N}$.

For 3 implies 1:
In a metric space $X$ being limit point compact is saying $X$ is compact, and so bounded.

Comment: Let $d$ be one of the metric of $X$. Try to prove that $d_{\phi} (x,y) = d(x,y) + |\phi(x) - \phi(y)|$ is also a metric on $X$ with the same topology as $d$ by using the continuity of $\phi$.

Comment: @Youem I've seen this on the web; was kind of hoping to use the clue he gives, because to prove that that metric is equivalent requires a bit more than my course covers.

Comment: Okay. But how do you want to use the hypothesis of a metric gives the same topology of $X$ ?

Comment: @Mariah Here's a slight varient on Youem's comment which I think might be more to your liking.  Using the clue, we have an embedding $X\to X\times \mathbb R$, and since the product of two metric spaces is a metric space, the embedding gives us a new metric on $X$.  Because the new metric is bounded, $f$ must have been bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 3. implies 1. can be more direct: Suppose that $X$ is limit point compact but unbounded in a compatible metric $(X,d)$.

Then there is for any $x_0 \in X$ a sequence $(x_n)_n \subseteq X$ such that $d(x_0,x_n) > n$ for all $n$, as $X \nsubseteq B(x_0, n)$.

This set $\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ has a limit point $p$, which implies (in a metric space) that any $B(p, r)$, $r>0$ contains infinitely many $x_n$. Take $r=1$ and see that this is impossible, as $d(x_n, x_m) < 2$ infinitely many times...

We do not need limit point compactness implies compactness. (this exercise could be seen as a step toward the proof of this fact).

1 implies 2: Indeed if $\phi: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $F(x) = (x,\phi(x)): X \to X \times \mathbb{R}$ is an embedding: the family $\{1_X, \phi\}$ separates points and points and closed sets, using a standard theorem (34.2 in Munkres).
This means that the product metric restriced to $F[X]$ i.e. 
$$d_\phi(x,x') = d(x,x') + |\phi(x) - \phi(x')|$$ is an equivalent metric for $(X,d)$ as well. (this can also be shown directly). As $d_\phi$ is bounded by 1., so must $\phi$ be. So 2. follows

Answer (score 0):

Your "For 2 implies 3" is wrong.

First, your notation like $\forall a \in A \exists a \in U$ does not make sense. Also, it is certainly not true that $A$ has the discrete topology as a subspace of $X$. (You could be given $A = X$.)

What you must have meant is that we pick a sequence of different points $\{a_n\}$ from $A$. The set $\{a_n\}$ has the discrete topology and you rename this set as $A$.

Further, $\phi: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with $f(a_n) = n$ is continuous.

So far so good.

However, your $j \circ \phi$ is continuous as a function on $A$, not as a function on $X$. You need to use the Tietze extension theorem to extend it to a function $ X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ to get the desired contradiction.